# Can I log a Laravel username using Doctrine and the MariaDB Audit Plugin?

Tags: laravel, mariadb, doctrine, audit-logging

I have an existing Laravel application that is using Doctrine as its ORM. I have a hacked-together audit logging solution for a couple tables, but now I want to expand my logging of database changes to a much larger set of tables -- dozens -- and my hacked-together solution isn't looking like the right way to do things.

I've checked out the [MariaDB Audit Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-audit-plugin/), and it looks nice, but I want to verify before I get too excited: Is there a way that I can use the MariaDB Audit Plugin to log not just the database username that initiates a change, but also the *application* username?

In other words, if my `.env` file contains MariaDB auth information for `MyServerSideConfiguredMariaDBUser` and Laravel user AliceSmith logs into my Laravel app using her browser, then makes a change to some data via my Laravel app, I want to know that Laravel user AliceSmith made that change -- not just that MyServerSideConfiguredMariaDBUser made the change (which will always be the case).

Does that makes sense? Is such logging possible using this tool?

Comment: Not easily. The very horrible work around is [proxy privs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#proxy-privileges). A trigger in the table to populate a column with the user (from user variable `@@user` set by application) and [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) to store history might be a way. SQL comments that include the user could also be make and end up in the audit log.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I'll probably just use Doctrine lifecycle events, but it's good to know that there's a horrible workaround if I for some reason need to do this on the DB layer.